# Any examples of Flot with floating tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, flot, graphing

I am currently working on a [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) graph, the [API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) which seems pretty powerful overall, although examples of advanced use are not widely documented.

The API suggests there are ways to set hoverable on the graph, not that I am sure what exactly that means I can do with it.

I would like to know if anyone could contribute some examples that they have come across, or code for that matter, which demonstrate examples of any of the following:

- Dynamic tooltips triggered by hover over events on Flot chart elements
- Tick tooltips (hovering over the xaxis shows detail)
- Any kind of hover over / dynamic event binding which has been used w Flot

The effect I am looking for is similar to [this](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/tooltip.php) Open Flash Chart example

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Have a look at [this flot example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/) which demonstrates tooltips for plot points on the chart. (Make sure you select the **Enable tooltip** checkbox.)

Answer (score 11):

There is also a simple tooltip plugin for it, you can find it [here](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip)

And I also add some feature to the plugin, you can find it on github. 
https://github.com/skeleton9/flot.tooltip

Comment: The flot tooltip plugin is extremely easy to use, for simple cases, all you need to do is add `tooltip: true` to your `.plot()` settings.

Comment: Consider using the original plugin, not the fork ;-) https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip

Comment: Do you know how to customize tooltip to be fixed (I mean. always show..)? we do not have much documentation on the friend google..

Answer (score 9):

http://data.worldbank.org is built using Flot and uses tooltips.

Comment: Do you know how to customize tooltip to be fixed (I mean. always show..)? we do not have much documentation on the friend google..

Answer (score 5):

The link in Simon's answer worked very well to provide a hook to use with the floating tooltips. However, I found that I had to dig around and cut code up in order to accomplish the hover affect. Here is the result (basically verbatim from http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html).

The only setting that needs to change in the flot initialization is in the options object. It needs to include this as one of the options:

```
var options = {
 //... : {},
 grid: { hoverable: true }
};
```

This function constructs and shows the tooltip element when called. The parameters x and y are offsets inside of the flot so the tooltip positions properly. The contents are what are shown in the tooltip

```
function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y + 5,
            left: x + 5,
            border: '1px solid #fdd',
            padding: '2px',
            'background-color': '#fee'
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }
```

This is the bind, it should only be called once when the element used as a placeholder for flot is available. It wires the event handler. previousPoint is used as a flag for displaying the tooltip

```
    var previousPoint = null;
    $("#flotPlaceHolder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, "(" + x + "," + y + ")");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how to customize tooltip to be fixed (I mean. always show..)? we do not have much documentation on the friend google..

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 - Nope, I don't. I am not familiar enough with flot to point you towards anything either. That said, having the tooltip always show sounds more like a *label*. Either way, I have stopped using flot altogether and switched to highcharts.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this library for tooltip and flot integration

https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip

Comment: Do you know how to customize tooltip to be fixed (I mean. always show..)? we do not have much documentation on the friend google..

Comment: No but that sounds like an excellent thing to ask as a new question :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#flot is my favorite JS tooltip library. Its pretty badass and has flot integration.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom data to the data array and use that to display tooltips.

See my answer and full example here:
[displaying custom tooltip when hovering over a point in flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349823/displaying-custom-tooltip-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-flot/12671873#12671873)